# How to find all callers of all methods in a specified class?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to output into file all methods, that are calling all methods in a specified class. I see that I could use ASM for this, but I cannot figure it out.

Example:
class A has methods aA, bA, cA.
class B calls methods aB -> aA, bB -> bA, cB -> cA.

I want to output "aB -> aA, bB -> bA, cB -> cA" into file.

My main goal is to trace all these calls from ExceptionFactory to service layer, and then output which service methods can throw specific exceptions.

The most suitable way for me would be, that it would run as a test, the file would be created during test phase.

EDIT: I actually don't know what class B is, I need to find out which class/classes calls class A.

Comment: Are you acutally interested in the callers - ie instances of classes - or the calling classes - classes where instances exist that call the methods in question? If you are trying to find the latter isn't this what any IDE can tell you with features like "Find References" or "Find Usages" or however it is called in your IDE. If you are interested in the first than having a test to create such lists won't help you because there will be different instances once your application runs at a later time.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I'm interested in the latter. Yes, it's actually the same functionality that the IDEs give you. But I need it in file, and to be done automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve something like above in your question by making use of `JavaAssist` library as given here : [Java Assist - Java bytecode engineering toolkit](https://%20https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/blob/master/javassist.jar)

This Jar file provides you with methods that can help you inspect your classes and its methods much more deeply to fetch that kind of information (i.e , methods in a given class are invoking method from which particular class) . For example , lets take example of this class `A` as below :

```
public class A {



    void meth1()
    {
        System.out.println("meth1 A");
    }

    void meth2()
    {
        System.out.println("meth2 A");
    }

    void meth3()
    {
        System.out.println("meth3 A");
    }
}
```

Now , let's take another class `B` , which has also 3 methods . Inside each of these 3 methods , methods of A are being called as below :

```
public class B {

    A a =new A();
    void meth1()
    {
        System.out.println("meth1 B");
        a.meth1();
    }

    void meth2()
    {
        System.out.println("meth2 B");
        a.meth2();
    }

    void meth3()
    {
        System.out.println("meth3 B");
        a.meth3();
    }
}
```

As you can see , methods in class `B` are invoking methods of class `A` from inside them . Now, we can make use of methods of JavaAssist library as shown below , to fetch the information that from each method of class `B` , which method of `A` has been called ? The `method.instrument` construct from the JavaAssist library allows you to build a bytecode manipulation expression , which helps you to list methods invoked per method and the classes to which those method belong . As a demo for your problem , i am adding the mapping to the method invocations in the `methodToInvokedMethodMap` , where key is the source class method from where method is being invoked , and value is the method which class information that is being invoked from inside method B , just like you asked in your question :) . Adding the code for the class `C` , which displays this mapping as below :

```
import javassist.*;
import javassist.expr.ExprEditor;
import javassist.expr.MethodCall;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class C {

    static Map<String, String> methodToInvokedMethodMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {


        Class thisClass = B.class;
        Method[] methods = thisClass.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {


            ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
            CtClass ctClass = cp.get("B");


            String currentMethod = methods[i].getName().toString();
            CtMethod method = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod(methods[i].getName().toString());
            method.instrument(new ExprEditor() {
                public void edit(MethodCall m) throws CannotCompileException {

                    if (m.getClassName().equals("A")) {
                        methodToInvokedMethodMap.put("Class B method " + currentMethod, m.getClassName() + " with name as : " + m.getMethodName());
                    }
                }
            });


            methodToInvokedMethodMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
                System.out.println(key + " invokes method from class " + value);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You can further explore JavaAssist library to find out different methods to serve your usecase . Also , in your Spring Boot project you can use this Jar as it is , or you can convert this jar as a Maven Dependency in your project and use it as a dependency via your `pom.xml` file . Hope this helps you resolve the problem you asked for :) .

Also , i'm attaching here how the output looks like for this :

[image]

Comment: could this be done without knowing the caller class? Or would I have to go class by class and check if class X calls class A? I've also edited original question to better reflect this.

Comment: For that what you can do is , you can make use of a combination of Java Reflection API + Java Assist . Java Reflection API will help you to inspect and list down all the classes in your project and methods inside them . And after you have listed methods from each class , you can apply filter on class name "A" as i have done here . Just explore a bit more around in the methods in Java Reflection API and Assist combined with help of above code, you will understand what i am trying to say :) . Happy to help !! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html

Comment: Using your comments, it works exactly as I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Attach a debugger to your running application and set some breakpoints using your IDE to the methods where you want to know the calling classes of. Then configure these breakpoint to log/write the information you want to some file (In eclipse you can find this under "Conditional" in the breakpoint properties, in IntelliJ the breakpoint properties have an "Evaluate and Log" section for example).

In these breakpoints you can for example use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` to access the stack trace and collect the information you want from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant that doesn't need a running application.

Open the project in eclipse. If you don't have a project for your application create a new java project and add everything from the classpath of your application to the new java project.

Then search for the methods you want to collect the callers. Then for each of those use "References" -> "Project" to find those. In the resulting search view select "Show as List" from the view options and adopt search preferences and filters to adapt the result to your needs. Then select every match in the view and just copy this to a file.

The file will look something like this (shown are references to `java.lang.Thread#interrupt()`):

```
acquireRead(boolean, long) (4 matches) - java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock
afterReadLine() - jline.console.ConsoleReader
append(LoggingEvent) - org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender
append(LoggingEvent) - org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
apply(Source, Target, List<? extends Factory>) - net.bytebuddy.build.Plugin.Engine.Default
awaitTermination(ExecutorService) - org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil
cleanUp() - org.apache.log4j.net.SocketHubAppender
close() - com.mchange.v1.util.SimpleRunnableQueue
close() - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
close() - org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient
closeKeeper(SolrZooKeeper) - org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient
createTimeoutException(Thread) - org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout
doConfigure(ParseAction, LoggerRepository) - org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
```

This method won't find reflection based calls.